How to simulate response data that varies over time?
I'm simulating some data for a power analysis, where we will test children's response times in an experimental setting and see if this predicts later language skills. The children will be grouped according to a third variable (here Group). The statistical model we'll be using looks something like this: language ~ RT * Timepoint + Group.
I'm having some difficulty creating the RT variable so that it varies over time in a way that is correlated within subject. It should increase over time with an effect of, let's say, 0.2, but of course this will vary across participants whereby some have larger increases and some smaller (let's say there's a jittered effect of 0.1). Similarly, some participants will have longer looking times overall, and some shorter.
The code we have so far is something like this:

# First specify the values for each variable in the model
SimulatedData <- function(
 MeanIntrcpt = 37.5, # baseline language score
 MeanSlope = 14.63, # overall effect of group on language score
 Group = 0.39, # estimated effect of group on language score
 time_slope = .2, # estimated effect of Timepoint on reaction time
 n_subjects = 60, # number of subjects
 n_timepoints = 3, # number of timepoints
 RandIntrcpt_subjects = 0.2, # Random intercept for subjects
 RandSlope_subjects = 0.2,   # Random slope for subjects
 Randslope_subject_time = 0.1 # Jittered effect of time between subjects
           ){

# Simulate data to reflect our subjects

SimulatedSubjects <- faux::rnorm_multi(
 n = n_subjects, 
 mu = 0, 
 sd = c(RandIntrcpt_subjects, RandSlope_subjects, Randslope_subject_time), 
 varnames = c("RandIntrcpt_subjects_StdDev", "RandSlope_subjects_StdDev", 
                     "RandSlope_subjects_time_StdDev")) %>%
 mutate(ChildID = faux::make_id(nrow(.), "S_"),
               Group = sample(c(1, 2), 60, replace= T))        # assign half the participants to group 1/group 2

# Simulate data to reflect timepoints

timepoints <- data.frame(Timepoint = seq_len(n_timepoints))

# create the combined data frame - simulated subjects crossed with timepoints

SimulatedSubjectsAndStimuli <- crossing(SimulatedSubjects, timepoints)

# Simulate RT data, 60 subjects * 3 timepoints = 180 rows

SimulatedSubjectsAndStimuli <- SimulatedSubjectsAndStimuli %>%
  mutate(RT = runif(n_subjects*n_timepoints, min = -0.5, max = 0.5))

}

SimulatedData <- SimulatedData()

SimulatedData <- SimulatedData()

> head(SimulatedData)
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  RandIntrcpt_subjects_StdDev RandSlope_subjects_StdDev RandSlope_subjects_time_StdDev ChildID Group Timepoint      RT
                        <dbl>                     <dbl>                          <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>     <int>   <dbl>
1                      -0.584                    0.0153                         -0.137 S_42        1         1 -0.452 
2                      -0.584                    0.0153                         -0.137 S_42        1         2 -0.265 
3                      -0.584                    0.0153                         -0.137 S_42        1         3 -0.0435
4                      -0.412                   -0.157                           0.169 S_15        1         1 -0.491 
5                      -0.412                   -0.157                           0.169 S_15        1         2 -0.176 
6                      -0.412                   -0.157                           0.169 S_15        1         3  0.152 
> 


As you can see in the data ouput, RT changes over time but not in any expected direction; it is random. How does one simulate data for a power analysis to represent the kind of change over time that we expect (i.e. longer looking times over time, which correlate within subject)?

This is perhaps more of a programming question than a stats (=cross validated) question, but I think your issue is that you create as many RT values as you have subjects, when you should create as many as you have subjects  x time points, i.e. 3 x 60.

I voted to reopen this question, because the comment by @Sointu above shows that it may be possible to provide a software-agnostic answer, that would be useful to people having the same question but who use other software or programming language than R. This wouldn't be the first thread here on how to conduct a simulation.

That being said, @CatherineLaing, it would be useful to provide an explanation in plain English of what your code is doing, if there's information in it that you don't provide in the rest of your question. Consider there are people who don't know or use R, but who could still give you some useful advice about your simulation.

I might be wrong, but I don't see (and a text search doesn't show) that your time_slope variable enters into your simulation at all, except where you define its value as 0.2.

It also seems that you are not modeling a random intercept of time, only slope (which is also apparently meant to be nested within the random slope of child which seems odd because these are crossed random effects), which is not impossible, but untypical. I'm not familiar with the faux package so I can't help with the code as such.
